# Laravel check if string is included in array of strings

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to determine if a String is included in a array of strings in Laravel.

I have

```
$rol = 'Admin';
$roles = ['Admin', 'Guest'];
```

I want to know if $rol is included in $roles without looping.

In Javascript it would be something like this

```
let array = ['Admin', 'Guest']
let role = 'Admin'
array.includes(role)
```

If I do this in Laravel, there are some cases I'm not expecting:

```
Str::contains($rol, $roles) //Output would be true
```

But if now `$roles = ['dmin', 'Guest']` instead of `['Admin', 'Guest']`

```
Str::contains($rol, $roles) //Output would be true but I'm expecting false as 'Admin' is not a $roles element
```

Answer (score 2):

- use `in_array` function from php.
  For example:

```
$rol = 'Admin';
$roles = ["Admin", "Guest"];

if (in_array($rol, $roles)) {
    // Matches
}
else {
    // Not matches
}
```

You can also convert the array to the type `collection` which is brought to your by Laravel framework. Just simply pass the array to the function `collect()`. For example:

```
$rolesCollection = collect($roles);
```

After that apply any conditions which are applicable to the collection type.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has a lot of [`helper`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers) methods. The one you're likey after is the [`Arr::has`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-array-has) method:

```
$role = 'Admin';
$roles = ['Admin', 'Guest'];

$contains = Arr::has($role, $roles);
```

This method is particularly handy when working with nested arrays. Using dot notation you can perform the same lookup without having to write that logic yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use [`Str::contains`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-str-contains) which checks if the string contains (e.g. has a substring) any of the provided values, but [Collection contains](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-contains), e.g. `collect($roles)->contains($rol)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it's not Laravel but PHP.
use [stripos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) function.

```
$rol = 'Admin';
$roles = ['Admin', 'Guest'];
if (stripos(json_encode($roles),$rol) !== false) {
   echo "Found It!";
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).